# 3 column div listing issue

Tags: html, css

I have a 3 column div layout and the 3 columns look fine. I'm listing items in each column however i'm having to set a min height for the blocks in each column and if the min height isn't big enough then on the next 'row' there is just a space.

However by setting a min height it means that there is a huge gap below the top row item if it's not as tall.

Is there anyway around this?

Site is here - https://steve-morris.co.uk/properties/rent

Each block has a gap below it and when the block isn't tall there is a bigger gap. I'm wondering how I set it so that instead of using a min height, the next row auto adjusts to the height of the tallest block in that row.

Answer (score 0):

You could set `.prop-list-title {min-height:290px}`. It looks like the title is the only area where the text wraps. Because it's responsive you would want to make sure you set that rule in the proper media display in your css.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some JS to determine the height of the largest box of the row and add a uniform height to all elements within the row.

Have a look at this: http://www.jainaewen.com/files/javascript/jquery/equal-height-columns.html